# Javascript unable to pass parameters into a property acting as a function

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Currently in a simplified form, my code looks like this

```
function AddFileParam(file_id, name, value) {
    uploadcontrol.AddFileParam(file_id, name, value)
}

uploadcontrol = new Upload()

function Upload() {
    //logic
}
Upload.prototype.AddFileParam = function(file_id, name, value) {
    //logic
};
```

The code is giving me an error as it states that addFileParam is not a valid function. This is caused by the instance of the function upload (aka. uploadcontrol). This is only occuring in Firefox/Chrome and not in IE. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Note, that the function AddFileParam, uploadcontrol = new Upload are in different files

Comment: You have additional casing inconsistencies, is it `Upload` or `upload`? Your posted code throws a few errors as is....need accurate code for an accurate answer.

Comment: Sorry, updated so that it shouldnt have anymore errors...

Comment: I'm not getting any errors with your current code: http://jsfiddle.net/dxGgX/ it's something external to this maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If the global `AddFileParam()` function gets called before execution reaches the `Upload.prototype.AddFileParam= ...` line then the `Upload` prototype will not yet have an `AddFileParam` method.

JavaScript executes from top to bottom. The exception is that the function declaration statements like `function Upload() {...}` are ‘hoisted’ and defined before the rest of the script is run. The `Upload.prototype.member=` line following that constructor function, though, is not hoisted, and runs in normal script order.

Though you can get away with using a function earlier in a script than its definition, it's not a good idea to do so for constructor functions.